# I want to add new checkbox rows in existing checkbox gridview table and also want to add that new checkbox row in database how will i do it

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is my code i used to add the `checkbox` in the `grid` control.also inned to add these result at end.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = " select menu_id from Menu_IDCODE where Access_Code in ('" + strParam + "')";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(ds);
    for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            CheckBox CheckBox1;
            CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSelect");
            //if (CheckBox1.Checked && String = "strConnString")
            string showId = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() == showId)
            {
                //check box checked and correct string

                CheckBox1.Checked = true;
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
```

old code:

```
<asp:GridView id="gv" runat="server">
<columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox id="cb1" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox id="cb2" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox id="cb3" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Not this way..i have used only one checkbox in gridview to show all data from database..now if in future i want to add more checkbox rows into that gridview. then what will be the code

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>